# Paypal rest api - how to get the return transaction id after execute

Tags: rest, paypal

I'm using the Paypal rest api and the sdk to build my shopping cart, after a payment is created (POST /v1/payments/payment) and executed (POST /v1/payments/payment/{paymentId}/execute), I'm trying to decode the returned Payment object to retrieve the transaction ID.

I've var_dump the return object and get sth like (just the partial return here..):

```
object(PayPal\Api\Payment)#137 (1) { ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PPModel":private]=> array(8) { ["id"]=> string(28) "PAY-2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" .... ["transactions"]=> array(1)  ...["related_resources"]=> array(1)
```

transaction and related resources exist and when I try to get the object value inside:

```
$result = $payment->execute($paymentExecute, getApiContext()); 

echo $result->getTransactions()->getRelatedResources()->getSale()->getId();
```

It said:

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function getRelatedResources() on a non-object
```

Is that sth wrong with my syntax..? the transaction ID exist according to var_dump recoard...

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
$transactions = $payment->getTransactions();
$resources = $transactions[0]->getRelatedResources();

$sale = $resources[0]->getSale();
$saleID = $sale->getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

related_resources in an array, not an object, so there's your problem.